# Customtkinter , root.focus_get() dont detect if the focus is on custom tkinter entrys

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

when I run this code for **Exemple ** then I click on the ttk entry and press enter it print ----> "**ttk_entry**"

But when I do the same thing to the customtkinter.CTkEntry it print **nothing **.

```
import customtkinter
from tkinter import *


def test(event):
    if root.focus_get() == custom_entry:
        print("custom_entry")
    elif root.focus_get() == ttk_entry:
        print("ttk_entry")


root = customtkinter.CTk()

custom_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(root)   #CTkEntry
custom_entry.pack()

ttk_entry = Entry(root)                       #ttk_entry
ttk_entry.pack()

root.bind("<Return>", test)
root.mainloop()
```

I was expecting that it print "**custom_entry**" .

Comment: Did you checked what `root.focus_get()` returns?

Comment: @Thingamabobs yes if the focus on ttk entry it return .!entry and if it is on the customtkinter entry it return .!ctkentry.!entry

Comment: `if root.focus_get() == custom_entry.entry` should work.

Comment: it works ... but i tryed that earlier and didnt work maybe I did somthing wrong .. anyway Thank you bro that helped me.